Track deposite transaction
I want to track transfer to a list of sol addresses. The transfer might be sol or usdt.
I can use subscribe events to get new transactions.
But, say I want to recheck transfers of last hour, how can I query the history?
I've check solscan api, it's pretty expensive. Any free solution?
